# Weight a foundation can hold

Tags: concrete, foundation, construction

Would a 6" slab with mesh, rebar and fiber hold a 2 story log home made from hemlock logs that are 16" wide? The mesh will be doubled up on the outer edges and rebar will run both ways. It's 32x40.

Comment: I am not an architect , but I can't imagine a structure that large with no foundation . And , what is your freeze depth?

Comment: Is it on bedrock? Sure. On swampland - probably not. The bearing of the soil makes a huge difference in "what can be supported" by anything on top of the soil.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information.  Where are you? Snow Zone, Earthquake  Zone, Soil type, Slope.  Essentially you're asking for a structural analysis with no data.

Answer (score 2):

Log homes are designed to distribute the weight of the house fairly evenly around the perimeter and with the logs being about 16” wide it could easily support about 3,500 lbs. per linear foot, depending on soil conditions in your area.

However, the reason footings (or as @isherwood indicated, thickened slabs at edges) are used is 1) to be installed below frost lines, which could be from 12” down to 48” below ground level, depending where you live, 2) help span across soft spots in the soil, and 3) removes loose topsoil which is easily compressed. Your slab does not do any of those.

In addition, if you have any posts in the middle of your house, that is a “concentrated “ load and will require an extra large footing with extra reinforcement.  A 6” slab will fail, even with rebar installed, as you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd almost certainly need what's known as a thickened-edge slab. It's basically a slab with footings integrated into its edges. Six inches is not considered adequate to support the weight of the structure.

Comment: A house in my neighborhood of tract houses (b. 1970-72) was recently razed and the foundation torn out with an excavator / bulldozer. The foundation was *much* thicker around the perimeter. I didn't measure, it but I'd estimate it was 18" thick around the perimeter.  Despite this a lot of the houses have had piers added to level the foundations. In most cases these piers are hydraulically driven to "refusal" at the soft limestone layer a few feet below grade. I have often wondered if perimeter piers cast as part of the original foundation would have prevented slab subsidence.

Comment: Is there a widespread tendency for builders to skimp on soil compaction before pouring slab foundations?

Comment: Yes, there *was*, and on soil assessment, and rebar, and concrete, and ...

Comment: In my experience as a builder we poured footings almost exclusively on "unexcavated soil", even if it meant using extra concrete. I can't speak to the habits of less conscientious builders.

Answer (score 1):

You really should get a engineer, not a architect or both.  That being said you need footers running under all support walls and posts, even a 4 inch slab has 12 or 16 inch footers under all load points.  You would also need to consider climate, soild composition, and compaction.  Due yourself a favor and get a engineer, the foundations the most important thing you mess that up and everything else is screwed also.